Client.connected is unable to detect the network disconnection in runtime. (WiFi.Client)

    void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200);
  pinMode(AP_SWITCH, INPUT);
  pinMode(con_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(network_led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(con_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(network_led, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AP_SWITCH), handleInterrupt, FALLING);
   wifiManager.autoConnect(AP_NAME,AP_PASSWORD);
  client.setTimeout(5);
   Serial.println("Connected");
}

void loop() {

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  if(ap_switch_flag == 1){
    wifiManager.resetSettings();
    wifiManager.autoConnect(AP_NAME,AP_PASSWORD);
    ap_switch_flag = 0;
  }
  if(!client.connected()){  
   if (!client.connect(server, port)) {
    Serial.print("dccqaec");
   }
    else {
      digitalWrite(con_led, LOW);
   }
  } else {
    send_serialdata_to_server();
    send_serverdata_to_serial();
  }
  if ( (!client.connected())) {
    slowBlink();
  }
  if ( (client.connected())) {
    fastBlink();
  }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    digitalWrite(con_led, HIGH); 
  }

}

Using this code i have connected the ESP withmy phones hotspot. It works fine. But when i turn off the mobile data, it is not able to detect the TCP disconnection. Also tried giving the timeout in setup.

"it is not able to detect the TCP disconnection" - because there is no TCP disconnection. TCP disconnection is an active tear down of the connection. TCP does not care if there is some temporary disruption on the path to the target as long as no packets are lost. This means temporary disruption will not be detected unless packets are actually sent and then don't get ack'ed. To detect such disruption when not actively sending data one can use TCP keepalive, which sends packets with no payload.
